# How to create temporary tables inside a postgres function

Tags: postgresql

The problem here is that by the time i go to the UPDATE block of code, i no longer have access to the data that was in subquery

I tried many variations of creating a temporary table and a select into from deleted_rows instead of the subquery AS part of the WITH statement but it did not like anything i tried, and it especially didn't like me trying to create a table after the initial with clause

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.aggregate_userviews(
    )
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$BEGIN

WITH deleted_rows AS (
    DELETE FROM user_details_views 
    WHERE ts < (timezone('UTC', now() - interval '5 minutes')) RETURNING *
), subquery AS (SELECT DISTINCT username, DATE(ts) as day_of_month, COUNT(id) AS user_views
        FROM deleted_rows
        GROUP BY username, day_of_month
        ORDER BY day_of_month ASC)

INSERT INTO analytics_summary ( username, day_of_month, user_views)
    SELECT username, day_of_month, user_views
    FROM subquery           
ON CONFLICT (username ,day_of_month)
DO UPDATE SET user_views = analytics_summary.user_views + excluded.user_views;

UPDATE user_details u
    SET view_count = u.view_count + subquery.user_views
    FROM subquery
    WHERE u.username=subquery.username;

RETURN NULL;
END;$BODY$;
```

If i remove the update statement it works perfectly, and i could probably use a trigger to do the update but i would rather not if i am not far off from a solution with what i have

Answer (score 2):

Got it, i had to create the table above the WITH and then fill it before the first insert and then use the temp table for the following two blocks of code like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.aggregate_userviews(
    )
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$BEGIN

create temporary table temp_userviews_table (username varchar, day_of_month date, user_views int);

WITH deleted_rows AS (
    DELETE FROM user_details_views 
    WHERE ts < (timezone('UTC', now() - interval '5 minutes')) RETURNING *
), subquery AS (SELECT DISTINCT username, DATE(ts) as day_of_month, COUNT(id) AS user_views
        FROM deleted_rows
        GROUP BY username, day_of_month
        ORDER BY day_of_month ASC)

INSERT INTO temp_userviews_table (username, day_of_month, user_views)
    SELECT username, day_of_month, user_views
    FROM subquery;

INSERT INTO analytics_summary ( username, day_of_month, user_views)
    SELECT username, day_of_month, user_views
    FROM temp_userviews_table           
ON CONFLICT (username ,day_of_month)
DO UPDATE SET user_views = analytics_summary.user_views + excluded.user_views;

UPDATE user_details u
    SET view_count = u.view_count + temp_userviews_table.user_views
    FROM temp_userviews_table
    WHERE u.username=temp_userviews_table.username;

drop table temp_userviews_table;
RETURN NULL;
END;$BODY$;
```